# Regular Expressions in .NET 2.0

Tags: regex, vb.net

Can somebody help to modify following regular expression to ignore commas if they are included in double quotes

Current regular expression -

```
,(?!(?<=(?:^|,)\s*""(?:[^""]|""|\\"")*,)(?:[^""]|""|\\"")*""\s*(?:,|$))
```

The only issue with this is that it splits string at each comma. Commas within columns surrounded by double quotes should be treated as one column

As an example, splitting this string "a","b,c" should result in two columns, not three.

Thanks!

Comment: Does VB.net not have a CSV parsing library?

Comment: Could it be that you would be better off with a [TextFieldParser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)?

Answer (score 0):

The following Regex is probably what you are looking for...

> \".*?\"

Comment: It's a legacy application that was running on .net 1.1 just fine, but regular expression doesn't work as it used on 1.0. I am trying not to make too many changes.

Comment: @user2835552 The TextFieldParser was new in .NET 2.0. It would probably have been used in the .NET 1.1 version of the program if it was available then.

Comment: I updated the regex to handle more characters. Let me know if that works.

Comment: sorry, \".*?\" results in same output

Comment: what is the output you get?